# Jenkins - git global config not loaded

Tags: git, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

I have verified that the git repository is being accessed by my jenkins user through the build task, and set git config for jenkins user.name and user.email, which I have confirmed using:

```
su - jenkins
git config --global --get user.name
> Jenkins
git config --global --get user.email
> ci@domain.com
```

However, the jenkins build cannot create a tag and returns `"*** Please tell me who you are."`, which I'm aware is because of missing git user and email. Any ideas on where I can start?

The git repo is being accessed in context of jenkins user. Do I need to restart server or git or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the Jenkins web page, go to **Manage Jenkins-> Configure System**, find the git settings.

You should be able to fill in "Global Config user.name Value" and "Global Config user.email Value" there.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I could use .gitconfig, but that will work too. Back to work :)

Comment: I don't know why it's not working with a external git, instead jgit.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to set the git credentials for one particular jenkins job, 
On your job configuration Under **Source Code Management** select **Custom User-name/email address** from **Additional Behaviours**. 
Put your user name and email here.